# What is the phrase in the Munich talmud, that is used in sanhedrin 59a, for what became oved kochavim?

Tags: gentiles, talmud-gemara, manuscripts, censorship

What is the phrase in the Munich talmud, sanhedrin 59a, for what became 'oved kochavim'?

I can see a talmud online that is probably censored.

https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.59a?lang=bi

> ואמר ר' יוחנן עובד כוכבים שעוסק בתורה חייב מיתה שנאמר (דברים לג, ד)
>   תורה צוה לנו משה מורשה לנו מורשה ולא להם
>
> And Rabbi Yoḥanan says: A gentile who engages in Torah study is liable
>   to receive the death penalty; as it is stated: “Moses commanded us a
>   law [torah], an inheritance of the congregation of Jacob” (Deuteronomy
>   33:4), indicating that it is an inheritance for us, and not for them.

The hebrew there, עובד כוכבים  is star worshippers (or literally - those that serve the heavenly bodies).  the English they put in there is 'gentiles'.

I have heard that   עובד כוכבים  is a censoring.  What is the Hebrew?

I understand that Munich is pre-censoring, or at least pre a big sweep of censoring.

I found a Munich Talmud here https://www.wdl.org/en/item/8910/  But it doesn't number individual pages with the 'modern' numbering system, and I can't find Sanhedrin 59a within it.

Comment: For further similar questions see this extremely useful site: https://bavli.genizah.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](https://daten.digitale-sammlungen.de/bsb00003409/images/index.html?id=00003409&groesser=200%&fip=193.174.98.30&no=&seite=694) is the relevant page in that manuscript. The relevant passage begins on the eighth line down towards the end of the line. The term for gentile used is גוי.

Comment: Note that the reading "גוי" is found in all manuscript witnesses: Munich 95, Reuchlin 2 and Yad HaRav Herzog. The early printed Venice and Pizarro editions have this reading too.