# Does the Munich Manuscript mention Oved Kochavim anywhere? Or is the expression purely a later invention?

Tags: talmud-gemara

Does the Munich Manuscript mention Oved Kochavim anywhere? Or is the expression purely a later invention?

For example, looking [What is the phrase in the Munich talmud, that is used in sanhedrin 59a, for what became oved kochavim?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/105780/what-is-the-phrase-in-the-munich-talmud-that-is-used-in-sanhedrin-59a-for-what)   the Munich manuscript doesn't have "oved kochavim"

I'm curious as to whether the Munich Manuscript has it anywhere. (e.g. does it have it in the last line of Avoda Zara 26a, or anywhere?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the search engine in [Genizah](https://bavli.genizah.org/FTSPages/FTS/FTSResults), neither עכו"ם nor עובד כוכבים nor עבודת כוכבים appear in the Munich edition. It seems it first appeared in the Vilna Edition, though עכו"ם appears once in the Yad Harav Hertzog manuscript (Sanhedrin 47b):
[image: עכו"ם in YHH manuscript]

Comment: Thanks. I see an option of https://i.imgur.com/mWAdbcd.png   but where is Munich manuscript there? what do I click to search the munich manuscript?  And what do I click to pull up the Munich manuscript Avoda Zara 26a?

Comment: @barlop I seem to have originally missed your comment. You need to sign up for free to the Genizah site I linked in my answer. Then go to the Hachi Garsinan-Bavli section. In the search engine, type the page and tractate you want and all available editions and manuscripts will pop up in a row. Munich is there, too.